# indicator-network and related controls not working on Ubuntu phone

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, phone

I'm having a few problems with my Aquaris 4.5 Ubuntu phone. The indicator-network screen shows nothing. Meaning I can't see wi-fi and 3G networks on the "push from top" screens. Also, I can't switch such options on the config scope (The only one that work related to connections is "plane mode").

Most strange thing, the phone is still working. That is, I can make and receive calls, surf the web (with both 3G and wi-fi, apparently). However, I can't make updates (it says "connect to the internet to check updates").

I've tried resetting the phone, loading up manufacturer mode (and tested everything - all working), but none were effective. Can you guys help me on fixing this thing?

I'm running the Ubuntu 15.04 (OTA-13) update.

Comment: As a last resort, you could reflash the OS.

Comment: @AndroidDev That's true, but a solution that I'd like to avoid...

Comment: 15.04 is EOL though...

Comment: @PauloNesello I am not familiar with mobile Ubuntu, but there should be a way to restart network manager service or something similar. If you have access to terminal , try `systemctl restart NetworkManager`. That's the best i can suggest. And as it was mentioned already, 15.04 is EOL, so you won't receive updates anyway.

Comment: Since you said you still can use the web, also try to reinstall the indicator. I'm however not certain whether or not it's the same package as on desktop

Comment: @Serg I tried the `systemctl` suggestion. Didn't work, terminal said `Failed to get D-bus connection: Operation not permitted`. I'll backup and install a newer version, seems to be the best option  :/

Answer (score 4):

I was having this problem too. Give this a try:

```
rm ~/.config/connectivity-service/config.ini.lock
```

It appears that this old lock file can remain in existence when it shouldn't, preventing the network indicator from being able to run.

reference: Antti Kaijanmäki, https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1615474/comments/27

Comment: Since OP didn't accept this I'm commenting to say this worked for me today. I deleted the file from the file manager app rather than terminal and it restored my network indicator without any further steps.